# Sending iCalendar to an user who's also the organizer of the event

Tags: c#-4.0, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, icalendar

I'm working on a C# application that sends emails containing a vCalendar event in its body. Say I (knockycode) would like to create a calendar event via this application. An email will be sent to my email address with the following body:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//MyCompany//Product//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20130819T084518Z
DTSTART:20051126T011300Z
SUMMARY:Testing that calendars get received
UID:MyOwnID
SEQUENCE:123
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="knockycode@lotusnotes.com":MAILTO:knockycode@lotusnotes.com
ORGANIZER;CN="Knockycode":MAILTO:knockycode@lotusnotes.com
LOCATION:TBC
DTEND:20051126T031300Z
DESCRIPTION:Some Body\NAnother Line of the body
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT02H30M00S
END:VALARM
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Take note that the organizer and the attendee is one and the same. This is so the organizer (me/knockycode) can actually have the event created on my mail client.

On Exchange/Outlook and gmail, the email is received (and I can RSVP to the event).

However, on Domino/Lotus Notes -- the email is not received (i.e. not shown in my mailbox). Though the logs in the Domino console do say the email's sent successfully.... If the organizer's email address was different to mine though -- the email does get received and shown in my mailbox.

Is there some configuration of the Domino server that would allow this email to be received?

Or something else has to be added to the email body?

Comment: If I save that as an ics file and import it into Notes 9, it opens up as an invitation and also shows up in the inbox. Apparently, the vCalendar itself is not the issue. Could you provide more information on the email itself? And also: Does the mail show up in the "All Documents" view of Notes?

Comment: The email's content type is text/calendar, and its body contains the "BEGIN:VCALENDAR ... END:VCALENDAR" text as shown above.

Also, I've just followed what you did: saved the text as an ics file and imported it. The invitation certainly does show up in my inbox that way, but I cannot RSVP to it. It gives me the "You must select an instance document to perform these actions" error message. Were you able to accept the invitation at your end?

Answer (score 1):

I think this per your last comment is working as designed. The ICS will just get you a notice on the calendar. I would go back to the Exchange side and use a new meeting form to get all the elements for interaction. If you pass a meeting notice to a Notes user (depending on the version that the client is using) from Exchange you can send invites out of the box. Notes can send replies back successfully in some instances. The issue might come up with reschedules and meeting cancels. These don't play well between systems well. Then you might run your present code to pass a ICS at the time of meeting change time/location. I would see how things work first then write your code. The ICS file will also work under remote devices like Apple iPhone/iPad.

Comment: The Domino server automatically deletes invites where the organizer is the same as the Notes user, because it believes it'd be redundant for the user to be invited to an event that should theatrically be on their calendar already; there is no notice on their calendar. I'm going to do a workaround where the organizer's email address is a dummy address so Domino lets it through; finally a notice on the calendar! As you said, there are issues with reschedules and meeting cancels. But if they scheduled a meeting via a third-party system, they might as well reschedule/cancel from the same system.