# :iCal Event not added into organizer calendar

Tags: outlook, icalendar, ical4j

I am creating ics file with 2 attendee and a organizer.

Event is properly creating for both attendees and response is also received when they accept/reject the event. I am sending same invite to organizer as well. On organizer end, event is not adding into their calendar (accept/reject buttons are grayed out). Following two messages are showing:

1. At the meeting organizer, you do not need to respond to the meeting.
2. Meeting cannot be found in the Calendar.

How I can change the event so that it also create in organizer calendar?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Appointment Confirmation Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20200506T190000Z
DTEND:20200506T200000Z
DTSTAMP:20200506T190000Z
ORGANIZER:mailto:test1@test.com
UID:Interview_47461@sterlinghoffman.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ_PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test2@test.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ_PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test3@test.com
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-486846808
CREATED:20200504T130737Z
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:at 3423 
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Phone Meeting
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tried with adding organizer as attendee but it not works.

`ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;ROLE=CHAIR;RSVP=TRUE;mailto:test1@test.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it sounds like the ics file is not being generated by the organisers outlook calendar, then two possible solutions suggest themselves:

1) On the assumption that it would be redundant / duplication to add an event to organisers calendar (who would be assumed by the application to have already created the event in itself) possibly the more robust solution for across calendar applications: add a sent-by, as per https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-4-3-organizer.html

```
ORGANIZER;SENT-BY="mailto:jane_doe@example.com":
  mailto:jsmith@example.com
```

2) This might be an outlook bug.  A quick search come up with same error messages https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2011/09/30/accepting-ical-appts-in-outlook-when-you-are-the-organiser/ and indicates a hotfix. See also [How can I add an ICS meeting automatically to the Organizer's calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349836/how-can-i-add-an-ics-meeting-automatically-to-the-organizers-calendar)

See also:

[iCalendar does not create an event for organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084236/icalendar-does-not-create-an-event-for-organizer)

[ics not updating organizer calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090923/ics-not-updating-organizer-calendar),

[Sending iCalendar to an user who's also the organizer of the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350871/sending-icalendar-to-an-user-whos-also-the-organizer-of-the-event) (the last comment to answer about redundancy to add to organiser

Answer (score 0):

Your iCalendar data has an error in organizer, that's why he is not being added to the calendar. As your organizer doesn't have any parameters and only has a `cal-address` it needs to be separated with colon `:` not semicolon `;`. Correct organizer property:

```
ORGANIZER:mailto:test1@test.com
```

For more about this property (and iCalendar) you can read [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3).

RFC 5545 specification of organizer:

> organizer  = "ORGANIZER" orgparam ":" cal-address CRLF

If this is not only about the organizer showing up in the calendar, then you can find more answers to an actual Outlook error in this [SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084236/icalendar-does-not-create-an-event-for-organizer)

Comment: I fixed that error (question updated) but still event is not adding into organizer calendar.

Comment: @Matis with ical.net, how do i make it have the colon instead of semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue. It was bug in Outlook. I followed the instruction given in following article and it works.

https://developermessaging.azurewebsites.net/2011/09/30/accepting-ical-appts-in-outlook-when-you-are-the-organiser/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940403/a-new-meeting-request-is-not-saved-to-your-calendar-folder-after-you-c

Thank you @anmari